# find length of json name/values pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

- In this code I'm using the 2 name/values pairs in each record
- I'm getting the alert with value 4 while I want to search the of numbers of pairs we    have that is FirstName,sal so I want the value 2 in alert????

---

```
var Newdata = [
{ "FirstName" : "John" , "Sal" : 10 }, 
{ "FirstName" : "Anna" , "Sal" : 30 }, 
{ "FirstName" : "Peter" , "Sal" : 30 },
{ "FirstName" : "Hemant" , "Sal" : 30 },]; 
alert(Newdata.length);
```

Comment: `I want to search the of numbers of pairs we have that is FirstName,sal so I want the value 2`. I think I didnt understand this

Comment: do you mean something like this? `Object.keys(Newdata[0]).length`

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like,

```
alert(Object.keys(Newdata[0]).length);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BaHx7/)